# How to keep only last 5 build of certain job using Jenkins CLI

Tags: jenkins

I would like to make jenkins' jobs cleanup more automate, but of some jobs (like with test results) we would like to keep last 5 jobs.
I usually use Jenkins CLI for deleting, but I don't know how to get build numbers of those I need to delete. Would someone know?

Comment: Why not using [Discard Old Build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Discard+Old+Build+plugin)?

Comment: We use it for common "traffic", but when somethig is release I do general cleanup. Usually disable all jobs of certain type, delete all build except some jobs where I need to keep 5 builds (even though the Discard Old Build plugin is set on 10).

Answer (score 0):

You can try go to the Jenkins master server

$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/yourjobname/builds

And then, run the following script

```
ls -ltr | awk '{print $9}' | grep -E [0-9]+
```

This script will list the folder info like this

```
401
400
399
398
397
396
395
394
393
```

You can try for loop them and delete the one you want to be deleted.

Br,

Tim

Comment: The problem of this is that this wouldn't work for multiconfiguration project as there is different structure (axis and stuff). I was hoping someone will know some command of CLI or using API..

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command

```
find /var/lib/jenkins/jobs -name "builds" -type d | while read dir; do (cd "$dir" && ls -d */ | sort -n | head -n -5 | xargs rm -rf); done
```